# Excel - compare two rows of text-based data to create rule hierarchy

Tags: excel

> I need to compare two columns of text-based data in columns E and F. The text in the cells is generated from a formula based on data from other sheets in the workbook.
>
> The rule I need to create is:
>   -`If both cells (e.g. E2 & F2) are blank, G2 is blank.`
>   -`If one cell (e.g. either E2 or F2) has text, this text is repeated in G2.`
>   -`If both cells (e.g. E2 & F2) have text, G2 is blank.`
>
> I am hitting a brick wall with the formula I have tried to use as it only generates text from E2. How can I create the inverse relationship between E2 and F2 to produce a result based on the rule above?
>
> Thanks.

`=IF(ISBLANK(E2),IF(ISBLANK(F2),"","F2"),E2)`

Comment: You are missing the AND() and OR() formulas. `=IF(AND(E2="",F2=""),"",IF(AND(E2<>"",F2<>""),"",IF(E2<>"",E2,F2)))` something like that...

Comment: Just for the sake of including the OR() formula I mentioned `=IF(OR(AND(E2="",F2=""),AND(E2<>"",F2<>"")),"",IF(E2<>"",E2,F2))`

Answer (score 1):

- If `E2` is blank and `F2` is not, return `E2`
- If `F2` is blank and `E2` is not, return `F2`
- Else return a blank string - this covers the "both cells have text" and "both cells are blank" scenarios.

Put this in `G2`:

```
=IF(AND(E2="",F2<>""),F2,IF(AND(E2<>"",F2=""),E2,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in G2,

```
=if((sign(len(e2))+sign(len(f2)))=1, e2&f2, text(,))
```